# Antd Multi Select Clear Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Below is the basic code from the antd website about creating a multi select option. What I want to achieve is create a 'clear' button. When clicking clear it will remove all the boxes with the 'x' that say a10, b12, etc. How do I clear out the box?

**I don't want to use allowClear, I want to tie this to my own button**

https://codesandbox.io/s/g0dec

```
const { Select } = antd;

const { Option } = Select;

const children = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}

function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select
    mode="multiple"
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    placeholder="Please select"
    defaultValue={['a10', 'c12']}
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    {children}
  </Select>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Comment: your codepen is empty

Comment: My bad, that is fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by making `Select` controlled component. This is how you can do this by using `value` prop of `Select` and `useState` hook.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const children = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}

const App = () => {
  const defaultValues = ["a10", "c12"];
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState(defaultValues);

  function handleChange(value) {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);
    setSelectedValues(value);
  }

  const handleClear = () => {
    setSelectedValues([]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        placeholder="Please select"
        defaultValue={selectedValues}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={selectedValues}
      >
        {children}
      </Select>
      <span>
        <button onClick={handleClear}>Clear</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-cherry-z6zh0

Comment: You can use the above code and just add the `onBlur={handleBlur}` to the select to bring back the state to it default state and then the implimentation of handleBlur will be  `  const handleBlur = () => {
    setSelectedValues(defaultValues);
  };`

Answer (score -2):

You can add the `allowClear` prop like so:

```
<Select
    mode="multiple"
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    placeholder="Please select"
    defaultValue={['a10', 'c12']}
    onChange={handleChange}
    allowClear
  >
    {children}
  </Select>
```

It will show up a clear button at the right side of the input when you hover it.

You can find it in the [antd docs](https://ant.design/components/select/) of the Select input

Comment: What if I wanted to tie that to my own button?